# Why is $X(\varphi^*f)=(\varphi_*X)f$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

My question is pretty much summed up in the title. We have a tangent vector $X\in T_pM$ at a point $p\in M$ for a smooth manifold $M$, a diffeomorphism $\varphi:M\to N$ for another smooth manifold $N$ and a function $f\in\mathcal{F}(N)$.

Why do we get that $X(\varphi^*f)=(\varphi_*X)f$ and what happens to the point $p$ in the transformation? Where $\varphi_*,\,\varphi^*$ are the pushforward and the pullback respectively. I came upon this question, when reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/445302/1156556) answer.

Comment: This answer only refers to functions. $X\omega$ is not defined for $X\in T_pM$ and $\omega$ a $k$-form with $k > 0$.

Comment: @Didier Oh I see. I'll edit the question. I'd still like to know the answer for functions in that case.

Comment: While the cited answer does only give the proof for $k=0$, it does indicate that the formula $d(g^* \omega)=g^* d\omega$ is true in general. For a proof of such, see for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1302562/137524

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, the pullback commutes with the exterior differential, but this has nothing to do with the actual question here, which is about the relation between the action of a tangent vector, the pullback, and the pushforward (which makes no sense for $k$-forms with $k > 0$)

Comment: Sometimes this is just the definition of $\varphi_*$. What is your definition for $\varphi_*$?

Comment: @ArcticChar I took my definition from wikipedia. There it's $\varphi_*X=d\varphi_pX$.

Comment: @ArcticChar And as I wrote it, I started to understand, that it follows quite easily from that as well. $(\varphi_*X)(f)=(d\varphi_pX)(f)=X(\varphi)(f)=X(f\circ\varphi)=X(\varphi^*f)$ Would this be correct?

Comment: @Wurstcake Usually, $Xf$ is used for real valued functions $f$, and $X\varphi$ would be misleading. That is why we use $\varphi_*X$ etc. ANyway, your proposal is just reading backward my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a function $f\colon N\to \Bbb R$, a tangent vector $X\in T_pM$ and a diffeomorphism $\varphi\colon M \to N$.
Note that $X\in T_pM$ and $\varphi_*X = d_p\varphi(X) \in T_{\varphi(p)}N$.
Then one has
\begin{align}
X(\varphi^* f) &= \left(d_p(\varphi^*f)\right) X & \text{by definition of the action of $X\in T_pM$},\\
&= d_p(f\circ \varphi) X & \text{by definition of $\varphi^*f$},\\
&= (d_{\varphi(p)}f \circ d_p\varphi)X & \text{by the chain rule},\\
&= d_{\varphi(p)}f(d_p\varphi X) &\text{by associativity},\\
&= d_{\varphi(p)}f(\varphi_*X) & \text{by definition of $\varphi_*X$},\\
&= (\varphi_* X)f & \text{by definition of the action of $\varphi_*X\in T_{\varphi(p)}N$}.
\end{align}
Of course, this proof relies on the chain rule, so using this to prove the chain rule would be a circular argument.
So let's just pretend that the chain rule has been shown, for instance in coordinates.

Comment: I see. Nice. But it should be $\varphi_*X$ not $\varphi^*X$ in the last line, right?

Comment: @Wurstcake Of course. I somehow managed to fail the only thing that matters in this proof, sorry. Edited.